# Rendering angular component conditionally based on its input variable doesn't infer the existence of the input variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, parent-child

I have an angular component with an array of Input variables that is asynchronously initialized in the parent.

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input inputVariable: string;
}
```

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  inputVariables: string[] = [];

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<string[]>('someUrl')
      .subscribe(res => this.inputVariables = res)
  }
}
```

Now I want to render in parent.component.html a ChildComponent for each inputVariable like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let inputVariable of inputVariables">
  <child-component [inputVariable]="inputVariable" />
</div>
```

In `ChildComponent` I can be sure that `inputVariable` is defined. However, typescript complains, that the type of `inputVariable` must be `string | undefined`. However, then I need to check in every usage of `inputVariable` in `ChildComponent` whether inputVariable is defined or not, which is not, what I want to do.

Is there a solution for ts to infer, that inputVariable always is defined for any rendered ChildComponent?

Answer (score 1):

Value for `@Input` is set later than on initialisation (on [`ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) hook to be precise).
To stop typescript from complaining, just set the default value for `inputVariable` like that:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input inputVariable: string = "";
}
```

It tells you to set type to `string | undefined`, because the default value of every variable in javascript is `undefined`. Giving it the default value of empty string, you don't have to worry about different types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To my understanding, ChildComponent is rendered once inputVariable exists, so for ChildComponent there should be no need to assign a value. Also if the value is not a string but a complex object, it can be harder to set a default value.

Comment: You're not fully correct. So the `ChildComponent` will be created even when there's no `inputVariable` passed. In your scenario, you're passing the value. The lifecycle of the ChildComponent will be: creating typescript class (with `inputVariable` property, that has no value (that's why typescript complains)), then reading properties from parent passed as `@Input` and then rendering the view. From my point of view, for a complex object, I always set the type of property to `mycomplexobject | null` and set the default value to `null`.

Comment: Well it doesn't really solve my problem. Assigning 'null' forces me to make null checks before every usage of the variable..

Comment: Then assign default string value as I did in the answer.. That's the whole point of strong typing in the typescript, to prevent from null/undefined values